# Something wrong with this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to python. Started making a tic tac toe game.

I've printed a board, so that's not the concern. My function play_sequence has something weird happening.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def display_board(board):
    print(board[7]+  '|'+board[8]+  '|' +board[9])
    print('----')
    print(board[4]+  '|'+board[5]+  '|' +board[6])
    print('----')
    print(board[1]+  '|'+board[2]+  '|' +board[3])

def play_sequence():
    move1 = ''

    while move1 != range(0,10,1):
        move1 = input("Player 1, choose a number:")
        break

    while move1 == input(move1):
        print("You chose 1")
```

I want the player to choose a number, and it should return you chose 1, and then the board with a 1 on board[1] on the board. Instead, I put in 1, and then a new line appears with a 1 in front of a box to put in another input. Any ideas? Then I put in another 1, and then it shows '11.' This is funny, but I need help. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `move1 not in range(0,10,1)`? Right now, you're comparing a number (string) to a whole range. Also, you'll need to use `int` to turn the entered string number into an actual number. Comparing a string to a number will always be false.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are using while loops. I believe you want to ask `if move1 in range(1, 10)` (by the way no need to write range(0, 10, 1) because step is by default 1, and also your tic tac toe board goes from **1** to 9 not from **0** hence range(1, 10)). This would be like saying "if move1 is not a number between 1 and 9, then ask for an input". I think what you mean is also `if move1 == ''`. There is also a small problem with this, which is that inputs are strings... so they can't really be compared with a number from the range. i.e. '3' != 3.

To easily change that, you can just do `int(input(".. whatever you ask for .."))` which converts the string into integers.

Just a side note but when you write `move1 = ''`, I know you're using empty string because you don't have anything, but you can also use `move1 = None`. Then you could also say `if not move1:` instead ("None" is False, so it's like saying if not False i.e if True).

Up until now, you've got:

```
def play_sequence():
    move1 = None

    if not move1:
        move1 = int(input("Player 1, choose a number:"))
```

Also, you could make it much easier by just saying

```
    def play_sequence():
        move1 = int(input("Player 1, choose a number:"))
```

because there isn't much point in making move1 when you are going to change it anyway. Unless I didn't quite understand why you were using the while loop... I guess you wanted to check whether the input is a number between 1-9?

Anyway, the problem you found with the weird "1 1 1" stems from this:

while move1 == input(move1):
        print("You chose 1")

Here, you use input(), and whenever you have input(), you actually ask for an input. That's why you're putting 1 again and again. If you write 2 or some other number for example, then the while loop stops. I'm actually not quite sure what you are doing here, but I *think* what you were trying to say is:

```
print("You chose", move1)
```

This would print the number which was chosen in the first part of your function.

Hence:

```
def play_sequence():
    move1 = None

    if not move1:
        move1 = int(input("Player 1, choose a number:"))

    print("You chose", move1)
```

I hope I'm helping and I didn't confuse you... :) Have fun learning python though!

Comment: `move1 = None` followed by `if not move1` is nonsense.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that is what Airmastix meant with `move1 = ''`, so I tried to keep it close to this original code... :)

Comment: Thanks. It’s works now. Now I need to print the board with an x on the spot where the 1 is

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm guessing if you really want to check whether the input is a number between 1 and 9, you can add this.

```
def play_sequence():
    move1 = int(input("Player 1, choose a number:"))

    # checking
    while move1 not in range(1, 10):
        move1 = int(input("Player 1, the number must be between 1 and 9"))

    print("You chose", move1)
```

Just one final point - I'm wondering whether you're going to make a super long function with all the repeats of the playing sequence... i.e. are you going to put move2, move3, ....? I think it would be best to use a big while loop for that. But I guess if you just want to practice for now, just have fun with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
def play_sequence():
    while True:
        move = int(input("Player 1, choose a number:"))
        if move not in range(0, 10, 1):
            break
        print("Your choice is", move)
```